# many-to-many performance concerns with fluent nhibernate

Tags: performance, nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation where I have several many-to-many associations. In the upwards of 12 to 15. Reading around I've seen that it's generally believed that many-to-many associations are not 'typical', yet they are the only way I have been able to create the associations appropriate for my case, so I'm not sure how to optimize any further.

Here is my basic scenario.

```
class Page {
  IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  IList<Modification> Modifications { get; set; }
  IList<Aspect> Aspects { get; set; }
}
```

This is one of my 'core' classes, and coincidentally one of my core tables. Virtually half of the objects in my code can have an `IList<Page>`, and some of them have `IList<T>` where `T` has its own `IList<Page>`.

As you can see, from an object oriented standpoint, this is not really a problem. But from a database standpoint this begins to introduce a lot of junction tables.

So far it has worked fine for me, but I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could improve on this structure. I've spent a long time thinking and in order to achieve the appropriate level of association required, I cannot think of any way to improve it. The only thing I have come up with is to make intermediate classes for each object that has an `IList<Page>`, but that doesn't really do anything that the `HasManyToMany` does not already do except introduce another class. It does not extend the functionality and, from what I can tell, it does not improve performance.

Any thoughts? I am also concerned about Primary Key limits in this scenario. Most everything needs to be able to have these properties, but the Pages cannot be unique to each object, because they are going to be frequently shared and joined between multiple objects.

All relationships are one-sided. (That is, a `Page` has no knowledge of what owns it). Because of this, I **also** have no `Inverse()` mapped `HasManyToMany` collections.

Also, I have read the similar question : [Usage of ORMs like NHibernate when there are many associations - performance concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740180/usage-of-orms-like-nhibernate-when-there-are-many-associations-performance-conc)

But it really did not answer my concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is rather vague.

Why do you assume many-to-many relationships are causing you performance problems? Have you profiled your application?

At a glance, if Modification represents a version or change to a Page, it should be one-to-many, not many-to-many. Maybe you have more of those.

Comment: Tags, Modifications, Aspects, etc. Can all be repeated indefinitley. They are designed as many to many in order to allow re-use.

Comment: I assume it because I keep reading how they are 'not typical relationships' in blogs and books about nhibernate, though I've yet to be presented any reason why.

Comment: @Ciel: well, you won't see that in MY blog :-) Everything depends on how they are used. But, again, do you have any actual performance issues that can be traced to those collections?

Comment: I am too inexperienced at this point in my career to really know that. I, personally, have not encountered any problems - but that does not mean they do not exist. With the disparate ways in which new patterns and practices are vocalized with a basic blog-to-blog distribution these days, it is very difficult to actually know what the consensus for doing things is.

Comment: @Ciel: you shouldn't care about consensus. Public opinions change every month. Read a lot, code a lot and make your own experience.

Comment: I agree with you, but that's very easy to say when you're the one able to answer people's questions. When you interview for a job, they generally do not think with logic like what is 'best', they ask questions about what is 'current', in my experience.

Comment: @Ciel: I'd run away from jobs that have that approach. When I interview developers, I try to ask questions that show their understanding of concepts, structures, architectures, tradeoffs, etc. and their willing to learn, as opposed to finding out if they agree with me.